# Get all HTML, CSS and Media content from a loaded web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a `Chrome Extension` and I would like to get all `HTML`, `CSS` and images/media content from the currently loaded web page.

If I use `document.documentElement.innerHTML` it gives me all of the `HTML` code as expected but has links to the `CSS` and image files.

Is it possible to get the entire loaded web page contents or would this only be possible using a scraper?